# When starting a Dispatch Timer, is it necessary to stop it first?

Tags: c#, dispatchertimer

Considering the following C# code:

```
                if (finalTextConvertTimer != null)
                {
                    if (finalTextConvertTimer.IsEnabled)
                    {
                        finalTextConvertTimer.Stop();
                    }
                    finalTextConvertTimer.Start();
                }
```

Is it necessary to stop the timer first?  One developer here says it's not.  Just looking for validation.

Comment: It timer exists (not disposed), then calling `Stop()` is safe without checking for anything.

Comment: If you want to *restart* it so it times the full Interval again, then yes.

Comment: Yes, @HansPassant. The intent is to have the timer start as if it were starting for the first time.  My co-worker insists that calling Start() does this anyway.

Comment: These kind of disputes are fairly silly when you can simply try it yourself or look [at the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherTimer.cs#181).  Easy to see that Start() does absolutely nothing if the timer is already enabled.

Comment: Why then, would Microsoft claim the Interval is restarted?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not researching in MSDN first.
From the method documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.start(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Start resets the timer Interval.

Comment: IF the timer is already started, then calling `Start` [does nothing](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherTimer.cs)